# Compare two maps in Golang

Tags: go, hashmap

I have two Maps:

First one:

```
map[11:manufacturer 2:upc 5:short_description 10: 4:category 6: 7:url 
8:image 9: 0:name 1:mpn 3:sku]
```

Second one:

```
map[3:manufacturer 5:mpn 8:category_path 10:is_in_stock 2:final_price 
1:name 4:short_description 6:thumbnail 7:url 9:furniture_type 0:sku]
map[news_to_date:2014-10-20 00:00:00 url_key:zanbury-panel-storage- 
bedroom-set price:0 media_gallery:[map[value_id:507779 file:/b/2/b217- 
31-36-46-57-54s-95-92.jpg label:<nil> disabled:0 position:1] 
map[label:<nil> disabled:0 position:2 value_id:507777 file:/b/2/b217- 
57-54s-95_1.jpg] map[value_id:507778 file:/b/2/b217-57-detail_3.jpg 
label:<nil> disabled:0 position:3] map[value_id:507780 file:/b/2/b217- 
54s-detail_1.jpg label:<nil> disabled:0 position:4] 
map[file:/b/2/b217-handle_1.jpg label:<nil> disabled:0 position:5 
value_id:507781] map[value_id:507782 file:/b/2/b217-92-sw_1.jpg label: 
<nil> disabled:0 position:6] map[value_id:507783 file:/b/2/b217-31-36- 
sw_-_copy_2_.jpg label:<nil> disabled:0 position:7] 
map[value_id:507784 file:/b/2/b217-46-sw_1.jpg label:<nil> disabled:0 
position:8]] sku_8:<nil> sku_1:<nil> shipment_type:0 url_path:zanbury- 
panel-storage-bedroom-set.htm custom_design:<nil> sku_5:<nil> upc: 
<nil> special_from_date:<nil> mk_expecdate:<nil> sku_type:1 
has_options:1 price_view:0 jet_price:<nil> categories:[11 10809]
```

How I can compare both and select those values from the second one which matches the first one.

Comment: you need to loop over both maps and compare the values one by one to check if values are equal.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I was just want to avoid loops, but I think this is the only solution for such a case.

Comment: In golang there are no work around which can provide a function to compare and return matching value. But you can use binary search for efficient solution.

Answer (score 1):

I did not understand much of your second maps. But my understanding of your question is that you want to extract the unique elements from the maps.

The result which I extracted is based on the value but not the key. It shows you how to compare 2 maps and have the result in the form of (key, value).

```
func unique(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    m1 := map[int]string{
        11: "manufacturer",
        2:  "upc",
        5:  "short_description",
        10: "",
        4:  "category",
        6:  " ",
        7:  "url",
        8:  "image",
        9:  "",
        0:  "name",
        1:  "mpn",
        3:  "sku",
    }
    m2 := map[int]string{
        3:  "manufacturer",
        5:  "mpn",
        8:  "category_path",
        10: "is_in_stock",
        2:  "final_price",
        1:  "name",
        4:  "short_description",
        6:  "thumbnail",
        7:  "url",
        9:  "furniture_type",
        0:  "sku",
    }

    for key, val := range m1 {
        found := false
        for key1, val1 := range m2 {
            if val == val1 {
                found = true
                fmt.Println("second map")
                fmt.Println("key:", key1, "val:", val1)
                break
            }
        }
        if found {
            fmt.Println("first map")
            fmt.Println("key:", key, "val:", val)
        }
    }
}
```

The output will be :

```
second map
key: 5 val: mpn
first map
key: 1 val: mpn
second map
key: 0 val: sku
first map
key: 3 val: sku
second map
key: 3 val: manufacturer
first map
key: 11 val: manufacturer
second map
key: 1 val: name
first map
key: 0 val: name
second map
key: 4 val: short_description
first map
key: 5 val: short_description
second map
key: 7 val: url
first map
key: 7 val: url
```

In order to show the clear difference between matched elements based on the value I used if found.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, the following should work:

Step I. Reverse keys and values in your 2nd map: `reversed_map_2`. This assumes that the values are unique.

Step II. Loop over values in your 1st map, now you can look up the values in `reversed_map_2`